How much knowledge of Scripture is enough?
I believe that after years of church going, one knows enough. Action is therefore key. Love and serve others as you would the Lord. That is my current stance.
To me (protestant), pastors are historians. Once you know the ebbs and flows of the Bible, all the rest is reminding. Which is a good thing.
Nonetheless, it is not enough, one must act. Love and serve. Am I wrong? I do value church, but I have Church. So, is there a point where going to church to learn is enough?
I am guessing that church is more of a community of people striving for the same ideal. Refining oneself to love and serve better others as one would the Lord.

Welcome to SE-C. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. Please also see the archive of 17,000 question/answer contributions as to how these policies play out in practice. 'Open' questions, which would attract opinion-based responses, may be voted for closure as being off-topic for this particular site.

Welcome to the site, your question would be improved by explicitly choosing which perspective you desire in your response (catholic? protestant? orthodox? JW? LDS? etc), or if you would like a more overview type of response. However, I will be answering this question presently because I believe you are asking a deep question, even if it might not be as academic as the site is designed.

I believe that after years of church going, most Christians are woefully ignorant of the Bible because they have not immersed themselves in God's Word. They might listen to a priest or a minister preaching from the pulpit, but have they ever read the Bible from cover to cover and studied it deeply?  A follower of Christ Jesus can never know enough unless they immerse themselves in Scripture and are indwelt by the Holy Spirit. You see, we both have our differing opinions, but what does God say to us from the Bible?

@Lesley Well said.  I used your comment in my answer.

@Kristopher The question is: which 30%?  The "minimum" in my answer is approximately 30%.

@Kristopher - do you mean knowing 30% of the Bible "is more than enough"?

@Lesley I was throwing number out there to show that it’s not really an answerable question.   Jesus said that the entire law covenant which was huge was contained in two simple statements: love God love neighbor.  Salvation is a heart thing not a brain thing.

@Kristopher - Praise God we are no longer condemned under the Law but our salvation is a free and undeserved gift.

@Lesley what percentage of knowledge of scripture do those two simple commands make up?      It’s a trick question


I believe that after years of church going, one knows enough.

If Christianity is a personal relationship with the Living God through the Lord Jesus Christ (many Protestant denominations),
and if the Word of God is living and active and able to discern the thoughts and intents of the heart of sinners whose hearts are desperately wicked,
and if a born-again believer is indwelt by the Holy Spirit who inspired and interprets and applies Scriptural truth in the process of sanctifying the new life,
and if that same Holy Spirit gives each individual believer spiritual gifts which are not for themselves but which are for the purpose of building up and edifying one another,
and if the Church as the body of Christ and as the temple of the Holy Spirit and as God's household are not mere metaphors but are descriptive,
Then there is no amount of either participation in the living Church or knowledge of the living Word that could ever be enough.
If one separates themselves from the body of Christ they are a severed body part, like a pinkie finger lying on the pavement.
Picture an open Bible.  That is God talking to you.  Picture a closed Bible.  That is God not talking to you.

I agree on what you said is most important: "Love and serve others as you would the Lord".  That is the goal for learning Scripture and going to church.
Your OP implies that you learn Scripture only through going to church and listening to your pastor's sermons.  I agree with @Lesley's comment that

after years of church going, most Christians are woefully ignorant of the Bible because they have not immersed themselves in God's Word. They might listen to a priest or a minister preaching from the pulpit, but have they ever read the Bible from cover to cover and studied it deeply?

But most churches are not intentional in doing expository preaching of the entire Bible.  If your church is like that, you need to supplement the sermons with personal Bible study, or Bible study with other people from your church.
Your question: how much Bible knowledge is enough?
I would offer this metric: "until you are familiar with at least these minimum", which includes the following:

every major Bible character including Abraham, Jacob, David, major prophets, major kings, etc.
every major story and miracles (those covered in children's Sunday school)
the general geography of the land where the stories take place
the general history of the major events from Creation to Jesus
the general history of the early church in the Apostolic time
every prophecy that the New Testament refers to, such as Isaiah 53,
every allusion to the Old Testament that the New Testament uses, such as every reference from the book of Hebrews, Psalm 110, Psalm 22, Psalm 91, Isa 61:1-2, Daniel's "Son of Man", the original Immanuel context, the prophecy of Joel in Acts 2, and many many more
every word that Jesus say including every sermon (Sermon on the Mount, Olivet discourse, Farewell discourse), saying, parable, miracle, commandment, commentary of OT, prophecy, nature of his relationship with the Father, etc.
every covenant God has made (there are 7)
major OT commandments, all New Testament commandments, either by Jesus, Paul, or other apostles
major teaching of the Apostles, especially about faith, hope, love, sanctification, sin, suffering, meaning of Jesus's death and resurrection, life after death, end of the world, etc.
knows the background and the outline of each of the 66 books

Once you grasp the above minimum, you will be "Bible literate" enough so that subsequent readings will be a lot easier because you can put the verses you read in a certain "big picture" framework / context.  Another benefit is that you also can better detect false teachings because false teachers use "half-truths" and quote verses out of context.
One way to achieve Bible literacy is to read the Bible cover to cover using a good Study Bible (such as NLT Illustrated Study Bible or ESV Study Bible) which has book introduction, essays, illustrations, and maps.
Conclusion
It is not about "how much is enough", but about growing to achieve Bible literacy to the minimum level described in the above "curriculum".  At this point you have "enough", but you can still benefit from studying further:

to fill in the details so you appreciate the story / the teaching more
to connect verses across books topically
to study the history of interpretation and to compare multiple interpretations with the aid of commentaries
to start noticing how Bible verses are combined by different traditions to form multiple theologies
etc.

But you should also aim to read from cover to cover devotionally by listening to what God wants to say to you through the reading and letting the text speaks into the context of your life that day so God can give you a fresh lesson to recognize new sin and to change you to be more loving.
Those 2 ways of reading the Bible (studying & devotionally) are complementary and will last a lifetime.

"But most churches are not intentional in doing expository preaching of the entire Bible." A lot of churches, especially liberal denominations, focus on the love of God almost to the exclusion of God's righteousness and judgment. And the same subjects are repeated year after year. But it is the responsibility of the individual Christian to study the Bible and know it intimately, to embed God's word in their heart and mind - not the priest or pastor or minister.

Jesus, via his words in the Bible, teaches my mind what is right.
The Holy Spirit changes my heart to value what I have been taught, to cherish heavenly treasures and not earthly ones.
The Father, through disciplining my habits and ordering my time, guides me to use my hands to love my neighbor through acts of sacrifice and service.
These sacrifices and the spiritual fruit that comes from them then teach me the deeper meaning of what I had been taught and magnify in my heart the value of the things I am now pursuing.
It is a circle. Every few years I return to Bible passages that I thought I knew only to find that they hold newer and deeper truths that I had overlooked. For example, when I first read Philippians, it didn't make much sense. It teaches that the path to joy is through considering others better than yourself and serving them. However, I suffered depression for ten years and believed that I had nothing to give. Surely helping other hurting people would drain me of energy and make me more miserable, not give me joy!
Eventually I listened to my pastor when he asked church members to visit a member who was in a nursing home. She suffered rheumatoid arthritis. I had never seen someone in such great and continual pain. I prayed with her, read her from the Bible, gave her a cassette of Christian music and left. I bawled for a half hour. I have never cried so hard for another person as I did for Janet.
Was I right? Does helping people when you are a depressed person drain you and make you more miserable than before? After the tears ended, I walked over a bridge on my way to church. My sadness turned to peace and then joy flooded my heart. I was filled with joy for a solid week. Neither before nor since have I ever been so engulfed in the power of the Holy Spirit. My depression of ten years ended and has never returned. After I left church that Sunday, I rushed home and opened the Bible to Philippians. As I read it, I understood it for the first time.
Following that, I took a bigger step and took in a homeless veteran and recovering alcoholic as a roommate for six months until he could find a place of his own. Decades later, memories of what happened on my visit to Janet gave me the insight that enabled me to finally understand the Book of Job.
It is a circle. Reading the Word leads to action leads to more learning leads to more action. Each harvest produce grain. Some you eat and some you plant in the next season.

That is the most deeply moving and accurate answer so far; I too suffered severe depression for years but before becoming a Christian. I only thought I was one, yet I could use massive amounts of Bible texts, being saturated in scripture. But the Lord heard my cry of despair, delivering me by causing me to see, from scripture, just who Jesus is and what he'd done. Only when the Holy Spirit opens blind eyes and unstops deaf ears will the truth and power of scripture start its God-ordained work. Oh, that people would stop thinking Christianity is a head-trip!

God treats us as individuals and leads us down paths that, with hindsight, were designed to teach us and bless us through blessing others. The more we delve into Scripture, the more we learn about Christian love in action.

I respect your opinion, though my answer is not going to entirely align with your perspective. I am eastern Orthodox and as such I will do my best to convey my answer from this perspective.
Your question seems to be divided into multiple questions.

How much knowledge of scripture is enough?
What is church actually for?
Knowing is not enough, we should act. I'm I wrong?

Short answers at the bottom, time for the long ones.

How much knowledge of scripture is enough?
Throughout history people have devoted their entire lives to studying and having knowledge of Scripture. So in some sense there is no "upper limit" to this. It is extremely unlikely that anyone would fully understand all of God's Word. We are not able to be perfect, only able to progress towards perfection.

St. Jerome (347-420AD) said even more bluntly: “Ignorance of the Scriptures is ignorance of Christ.”

I humbly answer question thusly: "It is never enough"

What is church actually for?
The Church is more than just a place to learn about scripture. It is not a classroom with a priest as a "history teacher". The Church is where the traditions of our Faith are safeguarded and we can be guided away from false paths (heresy).
Another thing is that you can only receive from the Church are the sacraments. If you willingly cease to go to church, you are excommunicating yourself from communion in a very literal sense. The sacraments are allow us to grow closer to God and to receive the gifts of the Holy Spirit. For us it would be folly to intentionally neglect ourselves spiritually this way. (Hermits are a separate topic, but I assume you are not an ascetic monk in the context of your question)

...if I am delayed, you will know how people ought to conduct themselves in God’s household, which is the church of the living God, the pillar and foundation of the truth. (1 Tim. 3:15)


... Therefore, brethren, stand fast and hold the traditions which you were taught, whether by word or our epistle. ( 2 Thess. 2:15)


Now I praise you, brethren, that you remember me in all things and keep the traditions just as I delivered them to you. (1 Cor. 11:2)


All those faithful who enter and listen to the Scriptures, but do not stay for prayer and Holy Communion must be excommunicated, on the grounds that they are causing the Church a breach of Order. (9th Apostolic Canon)

The is position of the original undivided Church is that you should have communion as often as possible, and even that those that do not stay are not actually part of the Church! This should give us serious pause, and we should strive to attend and not leave early.
I believe the simplest answer for a regular Christian is: "Church is for: maintaining correct teachings, providing access to the sacraments, providing spiritual guidance on the path towards salvation, as well as a physical representation of God's house in heaven where people gather to worship Him, and many other things"

Knowing is not enough, we should act. I'm I wrong?
In the Orthodox church we see salvation as a active progression, we refer to this as Theosis. So I believe you are not wrong when you say we must also act. We must do many things in addition to learning scripture, but Scripture is there to help prepare us for them.

All Scripture is God-breathed and is useful for teaching, rebuking, correcting and training in righteousness, so that you, a man of God may be thoroughly equipped for every good work. (2 Tim. 3: 16-17)

You must then do the things! Things like Prayer, fasting, worship, charity, self sacrifice, helping the poor, feeding the hungry, self stewardship of our own lives, and many other things.

You will know them by their fruits. Do men gather grapes from thornbushes or figs from thistles? Even so, every good tree bears good fruit, but a bad tree bears bad fruit. A good tree cannot bear bad fruit, nor can a bad tree bear good fruit. Every tree that does not bear good fruit is cut down and thrown into the fire. Therefore by their fruits you will know them. (Matthew 7:16-20)


And I saw the dead, small and great, standing before God, and books were opened. And another book was opened, which is the Book of Life. And the dead were judged according to their works, by the things which were written in the books. (Revelation 20:12)

That is not to say that we are saved by our actions and works, and if you want to go into detail about this subject please see my answer here to a question specifically about that. But here is how I summarized it:

"The Orthodox believe we are saved by grace through faith. A free will sustained by grace. But we do not separate faith and works, just like we do not separate scripture and tradition. In both cases each are intertwined with the other, thus we cannot say it is faith alone nor works alone, nor can we appoint ourselves the judge of who is or isn’t saved. Only that God will have mercy on all of us.
This is why God wants us to do certain things, it is part of our salvation, it is part of Theosis."  -Myself

We should attempt to learn as much scripture as possible, we should be guided by the Church in this endeavour, we should attempt to "bear good fruit", and we should have faith that the grace of God will cover our lapses.


You cannot know the Scriptures enough.
Church is more than a learning experience, you shouldn't skip it intentionally.
Faith and Works are two sides of a coin, you need both. So yes you should also bear spiritual fruits.

Peace be with you.
